# Failed unit test case (JASMINE)

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a function for which i am trying to write a spec which is failing with the error

```
Unhandled promise rejection: [object Object]
```

Function:

```
someFunction(a,b,c) {
    var dfd = q.defer();
    this.getInfo(b,c).then((data)=> {
       //do Something
    
      dfd.resolve(data);
    }).catch((error)=> {
       dfd.reject(error)
    })
    
    return dfd.promise;
}
```

spec:

```
describe( 'SomeFunction', () => {
    it( 'should reject when getInfo request fails',  ( done ) => {
        spyOn( utility, 'getInfo' ).and.callFake( async () => {
            var deferred = q.defer();               
            deferred.reject( { error: 500 } );
            return deferred.promise;
        });
        let promise =  utility.someFunction( a,b,c );
        expect(utility.getInfo).toHaveBeenCalled();
        promise.then().catch( function ( data:any) {
            expect( data ).toEqual( { error: 500 } );
        } ).finally( done );
    });
```

I want to write to here the test case for reject but then getting the error unhandled promise rejection.

Any one let me know if i am doing anything wrong here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `rejectWith(value)`:

> Tell the spy to return a promise rejecting with the specified value when invoked.

to spy `utility.getInfo()` method. Since the return value of `utility.someFunction` is a promise, you should use `expectAsync(actual)` to create an asynchronous expectation.

`index.ts`:

```
import q from 'q';

const utility = {
  someFunction(a, b, c) {
    var dfd = q.defer();
    this.getInfo(b, c)
      .then((data) => {
        dfd.resolve(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dfd.reject(error);
      });
    return dfd.promise;
  },
  async getInfo(b, c) {
    return 'real data';
  },
};

export { utility };
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { utility } from './';

describe('69378465', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    spyOn(utility, 'getInfo').and.rejectWith({ error: 500 });
    await expectAsync(utility.someFunction('a', 'b', 'c')).toBeRejectedWith({ error: 500 });
    expect(utility.getInfo).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
Test Suites & Specs:

1. 69378465
   ✔ should pass (11ms)

>> Done!


Summary:

  Passed
Suites:  1 of 1
Specs:   1 of 1
Expects: 2 (0 failures)
Finished in 0.017 seconds
```